# Using a txt file to name multiple colums in r

Tags: r

I want to name columns in a data.frame in r by using a txt file. I manipulated the original txt file to extract the text and made a list out of the prospective column names. But the problem is that I ended up seeing remnants of the list displayed in the column name which is not desired. I would appreciate suggestions what to do instead of creating a list? How to get the text and use it to name columns in r?

The columns names of the dataframe looks like this at the end of my code:

```
> names(mergedData)[3:6]
 [1] "list(V2 = \"tBodyAcc-mean()-X\")" "list(V2 = \"tBodyAcc-mean()-Y\")"
 [3] "list(V2 = \"tBodyAcc-mean()-Z\")" "list(V2 = \"tBodyAcc-std()-X\")"
```

This is what I did:

```
#read in the txt file
features<-read.table("C:/Adatok/coursera/3_getting and cleaning     data/Quizes/Assignment/UCI HAR Dataset/features.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> features[1:3,1:2]
  V1                V2
1  1 tBodyAcc-mean()-X
2  2 tBodyAcc-mean()-Y
3  3 tBodyAcc-mean()-Z

#removed the first column with this command
features$V1<-NULL

#made a list
features.list<-split(features, seq(nrow(features)))

#named columns
colnames(mergedData)[3:563]<- features.list
```

Comment: Have you tried, after reading the features-data, `colnames(mergedData)[3:563] <- features$V2`?